# PE format, what is the use for IAT Directory

Tags: windows, portable-executable

In the PE format we have Import Table Directory (accessed by `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT`) and IAT Directory (accessed by `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT`)
both are part of the Optional Header Data Directory.

Using the Import Table, the loader dynamically loads and resolves necessary libraries and functions.
This is done by iterating through the Import Address Table RVA (Thunk Table) which is part of the Import Table.

So, if we use the import directory for import resolution what do we need IAT Directory for ?

I've been reading the [Microsoft PE specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463125) but couldn't find an answer. Also, there are some questions in SO but most of them use IAT to refer to the Thunk Table and not the IAT Directory.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I think that there is a confusion between Import Address Table which is a field in the Import Table Directory and the Import Address Table which is called IAT Directory.
My question is regarding the IAT Directory.

Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

It is described well in the PE specification you linked, chapter 5.4.4.  They are the same tables:

> The structure and content of the import address table are identical to those of the import lookup table, until the file is bound. During binding, the entries in the import address table are overwritten with the 32-bit (for PE32) or 64-bit (for PE32+) addresses of the symbols that are being imported. These addresses are the actual memory addresses of the symbols, although technically they are still called “virtual addresses.” The loader typically processes the binding

Perhaps it is important to explain why it is done this ways.  A PE file is loaded into a process by mapping it directly to memory.  The underlying operating system primitive is a memory mapped file.  This provides several important optimizations:

- the memory used by the executable doesn't have to be backed by the paging file.  If the operating system needs RAM for another process then the pages mapped to the executable can simply be discarded.  To be reloaded again from the PE file when the process generates a page fault.
- the RAM used by a process for its executable code can be shared by any instance of the process.  In other words, when you start Notepad.exe multiple times then there's only *one* copy of the code in RAM.  Every process shares the same pages.  This is most of all important for DLLs, particularly the operating system DLLs that are used in every process, like ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll and user32.dll (etcetera).

When the loader fills in the IAT with the actual addresses of the imported functions then the operating system remaps the pages for the IAT and has them backed by the paging file.  So every process can have its own set of imported addresses.  The rest of the pages, containing code and the import table, are still shared.

Comment: The Import Address Table RVA and Import Lookup table RVA are both parts of the Import Table Directory. The IAT directory always pointing to different address and is not the same.

Comment: No idea what that's supposed to mean.  Of course addresses are not the same.  They are separate tables.

Comment: As I understand it, IAT Directory is different than the Import Directory and using the Import Directory is enough to resolve import libraries (with both IAT RVA and ILT RVA). So what the IAT Directory is for ?

Comment: That's what my entire answer was all about, I cannot guess what part of it was unclear.  Re-emphasizing, the tables at first contain identical data.  But when the program starts running, the IAT is updated with the actual addresses.

Comment: IAT and ILT contains the same data. but the IAT Directory (DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT]) does not.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I appreciate it. I am trying to mimic the loader behavior. When first loading the executable image to memory I iterate through the IAT table and resolve the virtual addresses. This works well and while iterating IAT and ILT are exactly the same. this is not the case for IAT Directory.

Comment: Of course not, it is the RVA of the table.  There are two tables so their RVA isn't the same.  I'm signing off, good luck with it.

Answer (score 5):

Nobody answers your question here. The reason is that IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT is practially undocumented.

I studied the code of ReactOS where they are using this directory to understand how it works. Then I wrote my own code to confirm my theory. Here are my results.

I will explain it based on the example of the 32 bit Calc.exe from Windows XP SP3.

When you list all directories of Calc.exe you get:

```
 0 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT
 1 VirtAddr: 00012B80  Size: 0000008C  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT
 2 VirtAddr: 00016000  Size: 00008A5C  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE
 3 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION
 4 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_SECURITY
 5 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC
 6 VirtAddr: 00001240  Size: 0000001C  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DEBUG
 7 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_ARCHITECTURE
 8 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_GLOBALPTR
 9 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS
10 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG
11 VirtAddr: 00000260  Size: 00000080  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT
12 VirtAddr: 00001000  Size: 00000228  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT
13 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT
14 VirtAddr: 00000000  Size: 00000000  IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR
etc..
```

You see that there are 3 directories related to import:

```
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT
IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT
```

As you see above the IAT directory starts at offset 0x1000 and has 0x228 bytes.
It merely consists of function pointers which point into the imported DLLs.
Each pointer has 4 Byte in a 32 bit process so there are (0x228 = 552) / 4 = 138 entries. I wrote a loop to list them:

```
Addr 01001000 --> function 77DA22EA
Addr 01001004 --> function 77DA23D7
Addr 01001008 --> function 77DA189A
Addr 0100100C --> function 00000000
Addr 01001010 --> function 77C41E2E
Addr 01001014 --> function 77C41D83
Addr 01001018 --> function 77C41EFF
Addr 0100101C --> function 00000000
Addr 01001020 --> function 77E59F93
Addr 01001024 --> function 77E605D8
Addr 01001028 --> function 77E5A5FD
Addr 0100102C --> function 77E7A9AD
Addr 01001030 --> function 77E536A3
Addr 01001034 --> function 77E53803
Addr 01001038 --> function 77E4E341
Addr 0100103C --> function 77E58D60
Addr 01001040 --> function 77E41BE6
Addr 01001044 --> function 77E52A2B
Addr 01001048 --> function 77E4177A
Addr 0100104C --> function 77E4C879
Addr 01001050 --> function 77E51B14
Addr 01001054 --> function 77E530C1
Addr 01001058 --> function 77E5AC37
Addr 0100105C --> function 77E54A69
etc...
```

This is the so called Import Address Table where the code in the module looks up the calls to external functions. If your code calls GetLastError() it looks here where in Kernel32.dll this function is.

The 00000000 in this list mark that another DLL is following. This list alone is useless because you don't know what is the meaning of these addresses.

IMPORTANT: Every executable has an IAT. But not every executable exposes it with IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT.

In case that the executable has additionally an IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT directory, the IAT comes with preloaded values. The bound directory consists of a chain of IMAGE_BOUND_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR and IMAGE_BOUND_FORWARDER_REF entries. This is the content:

```
Bound DLL: SHELL32.dll   Timestamp: 3B842039
Bound DLL: msvcrt.dll    Timestamp: 3B842039
Bound DLL: ADVAPI32.dll  Timestamp: 3B842038
Bound DLL: KERNEL32.dll  Timestamp: 3B842038
Bound DLL: GDI32.dll     Timestamp: 3B842039
Bound DLL: USER32.dll    Timestamp: 3B842038
```

The Windows loader checks if the timestamps in this directory when Calc.exe was compiled is identical to the timestamp of the DLL on disk. In that specific case the calls to GetProcAddress() are not necessary to resolve the imports and the preloaded entry points in the IAT can be used. This is for speed optimization.

Some DLLs forward calls to another DLL. For example Kernel32.dll has some calls which go directly into NtDll.dll. In this case there is a forwarder entry (IMAGE_BOUND_FORWARDER_REF) which allows to check also the timestamp of the forwarded DLL.

In case the DLL has been loaded to another base address the delta must be added to the addresses in the IAT. But I don't know where the original base address is stored in the image? When Microsoft introduced ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization) in 2004 it became the rule that all DLLs are loaded to a random base address.

In my case the preloaded IAT is completely useless because my Calc.exe on XP is from 2004 while the imported DLLs are from 2008. So all entries must be resolved anew. Once you install a Windows Update which updates some DLLs on your system the bound imports do not work anymore.

And the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT points to the exactly same addresses in the IAT (via IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR->FirstThunk). I printed the preloaded IAT and the values which overwrite them with the result from GetProcAddress():

```
LoadLibrary(ADVAPI32.dll)       --> HMODULE 77DA0000, Timestamp 4802BE8C
IAT 01001000 'RegOpenKeyExA'    --> Value 77DA22EA updated 77DA7842
IAT 01001004 'RegQueryValueExA' --> Value 77DA23D7 updated 77DA7AAB
IAT 01001008 'RegCloseKey'      --> Value 77DA189A updated 77DA6C17
LoadLibrary(GDI32.dll)          --> HMODULE 77EF0000, Timestamp 4802BE8A
IAT 01001010 'SetBkColor'       --> Value 77C41E2E updated 77EF5E29
IAT 01001014 'SetTextColor'     --> Value 77C41D83 updated 77EF5D77
IAT 01001018 'SetBkMode'        --> Value 77C41EFF updated 77EF5EDB
etc...
```

As you see the bound imports are quite useless in all these cases. The new values (at the right) are not just a constant offset from the preloaded values. They point to a different DLL. As Advapi32.dll is not the same anymore as when Calc.exe has been compiled they must all be resolved anew.

In the Calc.exe from Windows 7 I found the same scheme. But on Windows 10 it is different. It seems they store an offset into the DLL rather than the entry point address?

**SUMMARY:** If you write your own DLL loader you can completely ignore IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT and IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT. The tiny speed optimization by not calling GetProcAddress() can be neglected on todays fast CPU's.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for PE the IAT / IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT seems to be used for delayed loading of DLL

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format#delay-import-address-table

Comment: It seems to me it's a mistake in the documents. For any delaying there is IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_DELAY_IMPORT and this fields (in the document) points to _IMAGE_DELAY_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR. I can't realise what is IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT really means. ((

Answer (score 2):

The following article and it's first part is a good source for information on PE executable files:

From the March 2002 issue of MSDN Magazine: Inside Windows

**[An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)**

Comment: It does mention it. Look what table is on the right side of Figure 6 for example.

Comment: Yes. only as part of figure 6, and It doesn't say anything about the differences. When I examine both IAT RVA (which is part of Import Directory) and IAT Directory the have different addresses and different values.

Comment: The chapter "Binding" explains how IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT works. But IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT is not mentioned with one single word. I still don't know how the content of it looks like. It seems to be a Microsoft secret.

Answer (score 2):

`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT` eventually leads to multiple IAT thunks, which are stored in a memory region, which starts at `[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].VirtualAddress`, and has size `[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].Size`.

I guess it is useful when all the sections are loaded by default as read-only, and you can use `IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT` to make the IAT (but not the ILT) thunks writable.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. But it means that DLL's which do not expose a IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT must have the IAT in a writebale page.